# XSLT issue while rendering XML

Tags: xml, xslt

I am having issue while using above xml to the xslt. In the code, I wanted to print Id as an attribue of the forms. It is printing Id as attribute as well as the value of the node forms.

It prints output as :

```
 <forms id="AB1234">AB1234 </forms>
```

when I clearly do not need the value to be printed. What is wrong with this ? 
 
 **Xml.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"  encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="xsl.xsl"?>
<XML>
    <forms>
        <Id>AB1234</Id>
        <form>
            <Copy>1</Copy>
            <Fields>
            </Fields>
        </form>
    </forms>
</XML>
```

**xsl.xsl**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="XML/forms">
                        <forms id = "{(./Id)}">
                            <xsl:apply-templates />
                        </forms>
                    </xsl:for-each>     

    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="form">  
    Something           
    </xsl:template>
```

**ANSWER :**

Sorry to answer to my own question, but I figured it out. It was because of

```
 <xsl:apply-templates />
```

Here it was looking for

```
<xsl:template match="XML/forms/Id"> something </xsl:template>
```

And since it was not defined, it was printing out the values whatever were there.

So I added

```
<xsl:template match="XML/forms/Id"/>
```

to remove appending of Text element with the value.

Comment: It's good you figured it out yourself! But you really need to put the answer as an answer, rather than edit it as part of the question. That way, people won't think this question is unanswered, you see. Thanks!

Comment: Here's a helpful link on why that happens when you use `xsl:apply-templates`: http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#built-in-rule

Answer (score 0):

Posting this here since the asker hasn't yet:

> Sorry to answer to my own question, but I figured it out. It was because of

```
<xsl:apply-templates />
```

> Here it was looking for

```
<xsl:template match="XML/forms/Id"> something </xsl:template>
```

> And since it was not defined, it was printing out the values whatever were there.
>
> So I added

```
<xsl:template match="XML/forms/Id"/>
```

> to remove appending of Text element with the value.